# How do I update the API key, projectID, and AppID of Android Application using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have an android app that is using Firebase for email/password authentication. I continue to receive an error:400 message:

> Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs
> due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase
> initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key,
> Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.

Above this error message, it lists the API, projectID, appID that are incorrect. Now, I have tried the troubleshooting suggestions I have found on StackOverflow so far and I continue to get this message.

From my understanding, I should delete the google-services.json file and request a new API key. I have done this and have put the new google-services.json file in the root directory of the app. I have resynced the Gradle dependencies as well. However, the error message continues to return the incorrect API key, projectID, and appID. I have checked to make sure the credentials are correct in the Firebase Console, and they are.

Is there another way to change the credentials the application runs when connecting to the Firebase services? I thought the only thing I had to change was the google-services.json file but that is apparently not working. Google Cloud Console credentials are also up to date with the latest google-services.json values as well.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Have you change something recently? Like adding a new flavor with a different application id that is not yet configured in the firebase? Also there is the possibility to create firebase instances programmatically with different keys and IDs. Have you checked if you are using those values hardcoded somewhere? Have you tried a full text search for those invalid keys?

Comment: I have done neither of those things so far.  I'll try a full-text search to be sure but there shouldn't be anything.

Comment: Nothing has come up via the full text search

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by tracking down the values.xml file that is created when you connect firebase.

File path for mac:
app -> build -> generated -> res -> google-services -> debug -> values -> values.xml

I then copied and pasted the values from the downloadable google-services.json file into the cohort values in values.xml.

Comment: That is not really a solution but a workaround. It would be better to delete the build folder completely, run a gradle clean and build again. This should update the generated values as well. If you than have the wrong ones again, they are coming from somewhere... So you fixed the symptom for now, not the cause :)

Comment: Interesting. I appreciate the post! I'll look more into that.